# Google address api not returning values properly

Tags: node.js

I am using Google geocoding api for getting addresses.After getting the address I will split it based on the types and populate it in a form for editing.

Below is the response I get from google geocode api for an address.

```
address_components: Array(5)
0:
long_name: "Avenida Paulista"
short_name: "Av. Paulista"
types: ["route"]
__proto__: Object
1:
long_name: "Bela Vista"
short_name: "Bela Vista"
types: (3) ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]
__proto__: Object
2:
long_name: "São Paulo"
short_name: "São Paulo"
types: (2) ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
__proto__: Object
3:
long_name: "São Paulo"
short_name: "SP"
types: (2) ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
__proto__: Object
4:
long_name: "Brazil"
short_name: "BR"
types: (2) ["country", "political"]
__proto__: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The above response doesn't have the type "locality". But when I put console for checking, it returns the result which tells "locality" type exists for 3 times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locationa.address_components.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < locationa.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {   
    console.log("types",locationa.address_components[i].types[j].
        indexOf('locality'));
}
}
```

The above code returns the output as:

```
types -1
types 3
types -1
```

I am checking for the address which doesn't have the "locality" type. But still I am getting positive one showing it exists in the array. I need to show the value in the "administrative_level_1" in the city text box for the address which doesn't have "locality" type.

Can someone help me to fix this issue?